# How to make the most match item to the top in ElasticSearch query result

Tags: search, elasticsearch, search-engine

I'm using ElasticSearch to build a e-commerce search engine like [nexttag.com](http://nexttag.com) or [thefind.com](http://thefind.com).

There are some item like:

> 1. iPhone 6 Case - iPhone 6 Wallet Case , iPhone 6 Leather Case ,Flip Wallet Leather Case Cover with Credit Card Holder For Apple iPhone 6 4.7'' Black
> 2. iPhone 6 / 6 Plus Quick Starter Guide: (For iPhone 4s, iPhone 5, iPhone 5s, and iPhone 5c, iPhone 6, iPhone 6+
> 3. iPhone 6 Case, iPhone 6 (4.7) Flip Case [Hybrid Series] [Wallet] - Leather Case for iPhone 6 (4.7) - Kick Stand (PULPC-G-001)iPhone 6(4.7in) Brown
> 4. Apple iPhone 6, Gold, 16 GB (Unlocked)

When we query "iPhone 6", How can I make the "Apple iPhone" in the top, or not 'iPhone case' or 'iPhone quick guide'.

Comment: I think the best approach will be to use [Synonyms](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-word-synonyms.html), i.e. you'd need to pre-define "iPhone 6" as "Apple iPhone". Alternatively you could look at how you sort the results (e.g. by price) or use aggregation to enable users to add additional filters that describe the type of product that they're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would propose you to use the Function Score Query functionality offered by elasticsearch. The function_score allows you to modify the score of documents that are retrieved by a query.

In brief what you do is to add some post processing on the search results by modifying the score of each document by using a custom function (or more functions) that you provide.

You have various options for the implementation of the score function and your choice should depend on your specific case.

For example, I could propose you the field_value_factor function which allows you to use a field from a document to influence the score. That means that you should index the boost factor in the document (for example add a "boost_factor" field in each document and set its value to 1.5 for phones and 1.0 for cases or anything else). This has the drawback that you include the boosting inside the actual data and changing in the future would require re-indexing of data.

In this case the function would be

```
field_value_factor": {
  "field": "boost_factor",
  "factor": 1.0,
  "modifier": "none"
}
```

This will translate to the following formula for scoring:

```
1.0 * doc['popularity'].value
```

Please check here in the official documentation for any details: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#query-dsl-function-score-query